# Duplicate Entry Error with PHP When Trying UPDATE

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I am checking if a record exists, creating a new record if it does not already exist, and updating otherwise.  The SQL works fine in PHPMyAdmin but not through the PHP page.

```
$check_for_id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Members WHERE ID = '$id'");
if(mysql_num_rows($check_for_id) == 0) {
     // Not found, add a new record
     $sql="INSERT INTO Members (ID, Title, FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('$id', '$title', '$firstname', '$lastname')";
     $response=" Record Added";
} else {
    // Member is already in the database, so let's just update the info
    $sql="UPDATE Members 
            SET ID='$id', Title='$title', FirstName='$firstname', LastName='$lastname' 
            WHERE ID='$id'";
    $response=" Record Updated";
}


if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}
echo mysqli_affected_rows($dbconnect) . $response;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a syntax called [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) that does exactly what you want, in only 1 query instead of 3. There is also [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html), although it is slightly different (`REPLACE` is `INSERT` or `DELETE + INSERT`, `INSERT ODKU` is `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, if you have an auto_increment the results may differ a bit). It will be done transactionally, unlike on your code. It also assumes that id is a primary or unique key.